# Checking if vector 'space' in vector<vector<queue<msg>>> is empty

Tags: c++, vector, stl, queue, containers

I am playing around with containers, and at the moment trying to use a `vector<vector<queue<int>>>`. The form of this container is such that the 'first' vector's index is client ID, 'second' vector's index is priority level. i.e. a message of type `int` is pushed into a `queue` of certain priority, belonging to a certain client.

I am trying to find an easy way to find out if a client has any messages i.e. if any of it's priority levels has a non-empty queue. I used this simple piece of code to illustrate what I am trying to do:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    vector<vector<queue<int>>> node_pri_msg;
    queue<int> pri_msg;

    node_pri_msg.resize(2);
    node_pri_msg[1].resize(2);
    node_pri_msg[0].resize(2);

    for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        node_pri_msg[i].push_back(pri_msg);
    }

    node_pri_msg[0][1].push(3);

    if (node_pri_msg[1].empty())
    {
        cout << "empty-check succeeded" << endl;
    }
}
```

but it does not work i.e. it seems to think that the `node_pri_msg[1]` is non-empty, though there are no messages in any of the queues 'belonging' to it. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: It isn't empty. You resized it to two elements with the line that reads `node_pri_msg[1].resize(2)`, then pushed one more in with your for-loop. You may want to think about what you're trying to do again. You do know you're asking how many queues that vector *has*, (which you just set to two), not how many items are in each of those queues, right?

Comment: I resized them because otherwise I couldn't push the ints into the queue - I thought they would be initialised with NULL elements, which is when the .empty() would help. this is a wrong assumption?

Comment: That would be a wrong assumption. Resizing the vector as you're doing will create objects as needed to fill the resize (or destroy them in the event you're sizing downward, btw).

Comment: So just to clarify: 1. I cannot push elements in the queue without first resizing the vector, and 2. once I resize them there is no simple way to see if the queues are empty. Therefore, vectors of vectors wouldn't work?

Comment: The queues *may* be empty. That isn't what you're asking when you fire that `.empty()` method. You're asking whether the vector that *holds* the queues is empty and it is not. It could have a thousand empty queues in it, but that just means the vector is not empty (has a thousand queues) The status of the summation of all the queues isn't the answer you're getting with your current code. Judging by your problem description, I'd probably use a `std::map<>` for the second layer of this (and maybe the first layer).

Comment: thank you! I was initially going to do that - but thought I'd try this out as well anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would be better served with this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    typedef std::queue<int> MessageQueue;
    typedef std::map<int, MessageQueue> PriorityMap;
    typedef std::map<int, PriorityMap> ClientMap;

    ClientMap clients;

    clients[10][1].push(1);
    clients[10][1].push(2);
    clients[11][2].push(3);

    cout << boolalpha;
    cout << clients[1].empty() << endl;
    cout << clients[10].empty() << endl;
    cout << clients[10][0].empty() << endl;
    cout << clients[10][1].empty() << endl;
    cout << clients[10][1].size() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
true
false
true
false
2
```